How to check Python environment for hidden modules (not listed, but can be imported)
To expand on the title, my question comes in two parts:

Is it possible for a Python package to be installed in an environment as a dependency for another package, but not show up when you list down all installed packages in that environment using commands such as conda list, mamba list, or pip list?
If yes, then is there a way to verify the presence of such packages in your Python environment from the command line? My understanding is that multiple instances of the same package existing in the same environment could cause dependency conflicts.

Thanks!

rather than pip installing it, you could put it in any directory in your filesystem and add that directory to sys.path. You should be able import from main.py at that point.

Hi, thanks for your reply! To add some context to my question, I work with Python environments that have to be standalone and easily deployed on multiple machines. I understand that your suggestion of adding stuff to sys.path is a viable option, but it would involve some fiddling around that I'm not yet experienced with that would have to be repeated for each device. With that in mind, do you have any other suggestions/advice for the two parts of my question? :) Thanks!

If you're shipping a repository, add your modules to the repository and import sys and sys.path.append("relative/path/to/module/dir"). If you'd rather assume complete control of the environment (but not of the machine on which it's deployed), that's more docker territory
